# Предикатив или нет?

Tags: предикатив

Говорят, что предикатив это какое-то там состояние. Как например в безличном предложении

```
Мне хорошо.
```

Очевидно, что функция наречия здесь сильно отличается от функции в личных предложениях

```
Это для меня благо. // что?
Это для меня хорошо. // что? или как?
Это мне хорошо.
```

И что здесь **хорошо** тоже предикатив? Но ведь предикатив это слово состояния. Это слово из безличных предложений. А здесь у нас личные предложения, здесь скорее предмет-объектная модель. Типа как в предложении `Это благо`. Не скажете ведь, что существительное благо тоже предикатив.

Comment: Мне кажется, что "мне хорошо" - хорошо не предикатив, а предикат, сказуемое то есть, то что утверждается. А предикатив - это слово определяющее характер предиката. Мне жилось хорошо  - жилось - сказуемое, хорошо - предикатив к жилось. Мне сейчас хорошо - предикатив сейчас. С другой стороны, если акцент не на хорошо, а на МНЕ - мне хорошо, а тебе - плохо(тебе - не мне), - тогда хорошо может стать предикативом, а МНЕ сказуемым, а плохо - сказуемое.